# Add TextView to an adapter that extends BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I'm trying to pass a `TextView` from parse query to `Adapter`, and set the list adapter. The class `UserAdapter` extends from `BaseAdapter`.
I want the `ListView` to show one more `String`/`int` (using another `TextView`).
How can I do that?

**My code:**
Setting the `UserAdapter` to the `ListView`:

```
uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(li);
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(new UserAdapter());
```

The `UserAdapter` `class`:

```
private class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return uList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ParseUser getItem(int arg0) {
        return uList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    // How would I add another string when using `getView`?
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if (v == null) {
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null);
        }

        // I need to add another 'TextView' here.
        ParseUser c = getItem(pos);
        TextView lbl = (TextView) v;
        lbl.setText(c.getUsername());
        lbl.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                c.getBoolean("online") ? R.drawable.ic_online
                        : R.drawable.ic_offline, 0, R.drawable.arrow, 0);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Below is `chat_item.xml`.
*This is the `.xml` with the `TextView` that sets on `getView`
How can I add another `TextView` here?*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="@dimen/pad_10dp"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:textColor="@color/main_color_gray_dk"
     android:textSize="@dimen/pad_30dp"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_online"
     android:drawablePadding="@dimen/pad_10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewGroup` as parent view of both `TextView`s. A `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` may work best in your case.

**Here is an example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/pad_10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="@color/main_color_gray_dk"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pad_30dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_online"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/pad_10dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/pad_10dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@color/main_color_gray_dk"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pad_30dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_online"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/pad_10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i'm running a query on parse, and i'm getting a Different Int for every user, what i'm trying to do is to pass the Int on Use Adapter with the user name. this part: uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(li); pass the user Information to the UserAdapter and from their to the listView, i want to add another Int to the UserAdapter with :uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(li);

Comment: @DoronBenDavid - What `ParseUser` class contains? Post code of  `ParseUser` with your question.

Answer (score 0):

@user370305 stated the XML part. I'll describe the Java part. After you have inflated that XML file, then:

```
// Grab a reference to the first TextView
TextView lbl1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);

// Grab a reference to the second TextView
TextView lbl2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview2);

// Do stuff with 'lbl1' and 'lbl2'
```

Comment: I did that, can you please describe the java part?

Comment: @DoronBenDavid Which part should I describe?

Comment: first thank you for your help. i'm running a query on parse, and i'm getting a Different Int for every user, what i'm trying to do is to pass the Int on Use Adapter with the user name. can you help me with that?

Comment: this part:  uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(li);   pass the user Information to the UserAdapter and from their to the listView, i want to add another Int to the UserAdapter with :uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(li);